# Override file while backup database

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, database-backups

I want to back up a database using this code

```
sqlcmd -S servername -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = 'C:\backup.bak'"
```

It works. But if the backup file already exists, the data gets appended to the file instead of replacing the file. Every time I call `BACKUP DATABASE` the file gets bigger.

Is there an option for `BACKUP DATABASE` to force a replace?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
sqlcmd -S servername -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = 'C:\backup.bak' WITH INIT"
```

Answer (score 30):

`INIT` does the trick. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx):

> INIT Specifies that all backup sets should be overwritten

Answer (score 5):

`WITH INIT` is not enough. Should be `WITH INIT, SKIP` these days. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#Additional_Considerations)

Explanation: `INIT` overwrites only if some conditions are met. `SKIP` instructs to ignore those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

BACKUP DATABASE SQ_P TO DISK='D:\Data Backup\SQ_P.bak' with init;

where SQ_P is the Database Name

Comment: Please edit your answer! This question no need for new answer and your answer isn't minimum of policy for answer  question format. please read help center